# Serviço para pegar uma alteração no banco

Tags: c#, sql-server, rest, asp.net-web-api

Preciso do seguinte. Como eu faço para um serviço se auto startar sempre que a flag do banco altera de 0 pata 1. Tenho um campo em uma tabela no BD(Sql Server), que toda vez que o vendedor solicitar um desconto, a flag(FlagLiberacao byte) altera de 0 para 1 e nesse momento meu serviço deve enviar uma mensagem para o App. Bem isso, eu faço. Só não sei como o serviço vai fazer automaticamente isso.

Comment: Cara o banco fazer start de um projeto eu não vou saber te dizer, mas se o serviço já estiver executando você pode criar uma Trigger ou algo assim para quando alguém fazer um UPDATE.

Comment: Teria que ser através de notificação, tipo: FCM ou GCM https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?hl=pt-br
Também estou interessado um unir esse serviço ao meu WebService

Comment: @GabrielColetta, não é o banco fazer start. O que eu quero se é possível fazer um tipo de timer para o serviço, que a cada 10s, por exemplo, ele faz um select na tabela e ver se alterou. Se sim, então envia para o App a notificação.

Answer (score -1):

O que você quer é fazer um Job. Job é uma tarefa que vai ser realizada a cada x intervalo de valor e você pode implementar (não recomendo) ou utilizar uma solução terceira.

Conheço algumas como o [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/), [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), RabbitMQ ou até o [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/) possui soluções para fazer o registro de um serviço. No meu caso vou explicar o HangFire porque é o único que conheço.

Você precisa criar um Job recorrente, onde o servidor vai chamar a cada x tempo o seu metodo:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => MeuMetodoAValidarOBanco(), Cron.Daily);
```

Perceba que ele não usa o DateTime, normalmente para Job é utilizado o conceito de Cron. O Cron é uma expressão em string que você consegue trabalhar melhor com intervalo de tempos. O proprio HangFire da algumas opções mais simples, porém existe esse [site](http://www.cronmaker.com/) onde você pode gerar suas expressões.

Por ser um serviço, você pode subir ele como serviço do Windows ou até mesmo subir na sua API. O único problema desse último é que o IIS limpa o pool quando ninguém acessa a API. Segue o [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140841/c-hangfire-parando) para uma pergunta relacionada aqui no Stack.

Comment: O cliente preferiu(melhor) fazer a alteração em seu sistema e enviar por parâmetro para um serviço que ao receber o parâmetro, o serviço então dispara a notificação. Achei melhor assim. Um serviço/processamento a menos.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar um `Windows Service` com uma `SqlDependency`

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    SqlDependency.Stop(this.ConnectionString);
    SqlDependency.Start(this.ConnectionString);
    Task.Run(Monitorar);
}

protected override void OnStop()
{   
    SqlDependency.Stop(this.ConnectionString);
}

private async Task Monitorar()
{
    await SqlDependencyOnChange(null, null);
}

private async Task SqlDependencyOnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    var flag = false;
    using (var conexao = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
    {
        await conexao.OpenAsync();
        using (var comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT Flag FROM Tabela", conexao))
        {
            var depedency = new SqlDependency(comando);
            depedency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(async (_sender, _e) => {
                await SqlDependencyOnChange(_sender, _e);
            });

            var result = comando.ExecuteScalar();
            if (result != null || result != DBNull.Value)
                flag = (bool)result;
        }
    }

    if (flag)
    {
        await Processar();
    }
}

private async Task Processar()
{
    //Envie a notificação para o seu App.
}
```

Lembrando que o BROKER deverá está ativo no seu `Sql Server`.:

```
ALTER DATABASE [Database] SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```